# Toggle Active State in Vue before processing the rest of the DOM

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, vue.js

I currently have a project that I recently moved over to Vue.js. I have completed the migration and everything works fine, the only thing i'm trying to improve on, is the webapps response times on devices like tablets that don't have enough processing power to calculate all the changes in a decent amount of time.

Currently I have a list of items and when you select one it updates the DOM on the right will all the calculated data, as well as sets the active class with the `v-bind:class` attribute.

Is there a way to toggle the new active class and remove the previous one (With a transition eventually) before / asynchronously while Vue calculates and displays the updated DOM information on the right?

Answer (score 0):

you would have to wrap the expensive function in a promise, or at least a timeout.

```
someMethod() {
  var _this = this
  this.setnewClassHere

  var mypromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    _this.expensiveFunction() // will runy async, so the above setNewClassHere will have effect before expensiveFunction is finished.

    resolve() // resolve the promise. This will execute the follwing .then() function.

  })
  .then(function(result) {
    _this.setBackTheClassHere
    // when async operation is finished, we set back the class
    // no idea if you need this in your case.
  })
}
```

Comment: This sounds great! The only thing im not 100% sure about, is that all my processing is happening in a "computed" Vue variable that changed when I updated my store. Is there a way to change the active state and force a DOM update while it calculates the computed elements in the background?